# How to access view generator parameters in ASP.NET MVC 3 T4 template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I want to create custom template to generate view in ASP.NET MVC 3. Inside the template, I want to get the name of the selected controller. Where can I find it?

Actually there are several things I want to find out:

- controller name: ...?
- action name: ...
- viewmodel name: Host.ViewDataTypeName
- view name: Host.ViewName

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) on changing the MVC default templates?

It's also worth taking a look at [Where can I find the API specification for MvcTextTemplateHost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938872/where-can-i-find-the-api-specification-for-mvctexttemplatehost)