# How to change default view creation logic in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, overriding

I've looked [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938872/where-can-i-find-the-api-specification-for-mvctexttemplatehost) to try to answer this question as well as a billion Google searches, but have yet to come up with a solution.

My directory structure is a `multi-tenant MVC site` with an `overridden view engine` that uses `Areas` to serve content for different hosts that share a lot of common logic `served globally from the base controllers and views folders`. We have taken this a step further and broken out different `global site sections` into a `new folder called SiteSections`. Inside of this folder we have more Areas.

The issue I am having, is whenever I try to use the visual studio context menu from inside a controller that is inside the `SiteSections` folder, it always adds it to the global `Views` folder.

[image: Visual Studio Context Menu]

What I am assuming is happening is that since these are `Areas` held within a different directory, Visual Studio is searching the `Areas` folder for an `Area` with the name of which I am working in. Since this is kept in a different directory, it is just defaulting to the `global` one. I've looked into all the different `T4 templates` and do not see anything specifying the directory where the view will be created.

I have just one question, that I'm hoping is possible.

How can I override Visual Studio to look in a second directory for the Area in question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something like that, not with Areas, but with Folders.

Have you tried to add custom view engine on ViewEngines?

The steps that i followed:

1 - I put this line at Global.asax.cs on method Application_Start:
ViewsEngines.Engines.Add(new MyCustomViewEngine());

2 - I created the file named as MyCustomViewEngine inheriting from RazorViewEngine, for example:

```
public class MyCustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyCustomViewEngine()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = MyViewLocationFormats;
    }

    private static string[] MyViewLocationFormats = new[]
    {
        "~/Views/Folder/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Folder_1/Folder_2/{0}.cshtml"
    }
}
```

I think that you can use in this way: "~/Areas/Views/Folder/{0}.cshtml",

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a custom ViewEngine that I have no problem configuring to serve the files properly. My issue is with Visual Studio and where it is creating files when I use the context menu and select "Add View." It always overwrites the global file if there is one.